# Keystone: Pass mongoose connection into Keystone options

Tags: node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

Looking at the documentation, it is possible to pass an instance of Mongoose into the Keystone options:

```
http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/
```

"mongoose Object: Instance of Mongoose to be used instead of the default instance."

But how...? How do I get the instance from Mongoose?

Answer (score 3):

You need to require `mongoose` yourself, configure it, and then pass it to keystone under the mongoose key

```
var yourMongoose = require('mongoose')

// init mongoose

keystone.init({mongoose: yourMongoose})
```